# Who wears a talis on leil Shabbos?

Tags: minhag, tallit-gadol, leil-shabbat

Rabbi Chanina would don his talis gadol on erev Shabbos (Mas. Shabbos 25b, Rambam Hilchos Shabbos 30:2). While this has been practiced by individuals, is it today the practice of any particular segments of Jewry to wear their taleisim for Friday night prayers (and, perhaps, meals)?

Comment: I saw this once in the shul in [Yitzhar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzhar).

Comment: I recall hearing Karlin-Stolin wears a _talis_ for Friday night prayers.

Comment: @DoubleAA Did the shul in Yitzhar follow a particular minhag in this effect? Was it Rav Shapira's shul?

Comment: @yoel I was only there once so I can't say very much specific, except that it wasn't everyone in the shul doing it. Probably about 60% or so.

Answer (score 1):

The custom of the Teimanin (Yemenites) is to wear a tallis for Friday night prayers. (And I was told by my Teimani neighbor that also when they visit a friend on Shabbos they wear a tallis). But despite this being an old, established custom, many Teimanim who came to Eretz Yisrael have abandoned it, apparently so as not to be different from other Jewish groups.

See [here](http://www.nosachteiman.co.il/?CategoryID=473&ArticleID=6287).