# Why does the Chazzan Wear a Tallit on Friday Night?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, tallit-gadol, leil-shabbat, kabbalat-shabbat

Generally, the Chazzan \ Shaliach Tzibbur for Maariv does not wear a Tallit.  However, on Friday Nights, he does.  Why is this night different than all other nights?

Comment: In my shul (and in many other shuls) the shaliach tzibur wears a tallit every night

Comment: @Daniel - Interesting. I don't recall seeing this, but I'll have to pay more attention when I'm visiting other shuls.

Comment: I believe this is standard in nusach Ashkenaz shuls

Comment: @Daniel, wearing a tallis for maariv is a Yekkisch minhag. In many non-Yekkisch minyanim, such as the one with which I daven, they have no such hakpada (unfortunately). On the other hand, I've heard of yeshivish minyanim where one has to either wear a jacket or a tallis. According to R' Hamburger, the correct procedure is to take off one's jacket so as to need to wear the tallis, as it adds an extra layer of decorum which is not present when one is only wearing a jacket.

Comment: This is the 'good chop' answer to your question http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26147/759. The better answer is, as Daniel hinted, that different places do different things [and don't think about it to much].

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20414/covering-your-head-with-a-tallis-at-night-problem. Also please see 
See http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=7540 . 
The issue relates to minhogim.

Comment: I think that Shabbat and Yom Tov have an extra sense of *kedusha* that causes the more common minhag of wearing tallit, that normally would not be done on a weekday. I'll try to research further. +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: Somewhat related is http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20414/5275. I viewed the link to the Mishnah Brurah, there, and he indicates various references related to *Kavod Hatzibur*. I assume then, that Shabbat & Yom Tov, the Chazan need to present a greater sense of Kavod Hatzibur then is needed during the weekday. An assumption, but, I can't explain why that would be.

Comment: Vaguely recall someone mentioned to me that Kabbalat Shabbat is similar to a wedding where The Shabbat is the kallah (bride) and we are the chattan (groom). There is a minhag that the chattan and kalla wear a tallit at the wedding, or the chuppah is a tallit on a pole. (No ta minhag followed by all, but that may be the source for this Fri. night minhag.) This explains Kabbalat Shabbat. I guess it would be improper to remove the tallit before the Ma'ariv section?